Confusion in tunnelling problem in QM
There was a problem solved in our introductory QM class where we were given a system in which the potential varies as

$V= 0$ for $x<0$ and $V=V_{o}$ for $x≥0$

Now we solved the Schrodinger equation for the condition that total energy $E$ is less than $V_o$ and obtained the wavefunction (the part for the region $x≥0$ came out to be $A exp(-lx)$ where $l^2=\frac{2m(V_o-E)}{\hbar^2}$.
Now what I didn't understand from the solution was that when I applied the kinetic energy operator $\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} $ on the above solution it turned out to have a negative eigenvalue which doesn't make any sense at all (to be precise the eigenvalue was $\frac{\hbar^2 l^2}{2m}$).
So what really does the negative value of that eigenvalue signify ?

what do you mean "eigenvalue"?

I might be misunderstanding what you were trying to do by applying the operator $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ on your wavefunction so do correct me if I'm misinterpreting things but here's a response based on what I think you were doing.
When you solve the Schrodinger equation for the given potential, you should be solving two equations, one for positive x and one for negative x. For the negative x case, your potential $V(x)$ is equal to zero so your Hamiltonian is just the kinetic energy term $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$. Your Schrodinger equation should read:
$- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2} \psi(x) = E \psi(x)$
Then for the positive x case, you have a non-zero value $V(x) = V_0$ so your Schrodinger equation now reads:
$- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2} \psi(x) + V_0 \psi(x) = E \psi(x)$
The solution you have provided is just the wavefunction for the positive x case. I'm assuming that you got your answer for the kinetic energy of the particle by applying $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ to this result, which would pull out the eigenvalue $- \frac{ħ^{2}l^2}{2m}$.
I think you are misunderstanding how the Hamiltonian acts on the wavefunction. For one, the fact that your wavefunction in the positive x part is even an eigenfunction of the operator $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ in the first place is purely a coincidence due to the fact that there is no position dependence in your potential within the positive x region. There isn't anything physically meaningful in this and the eigenvalue $- \frac{ħ^{2}l^2}{2m}$ doesn't correspond to any physically meaningful quantities.
This is because the operator $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ is not a general kinetic energy operator for a general wavefunction, which is how I think you might be using it. Instead it is the Hamiltonian of a free particle, where a free particle is a particle moving freely in the absence of any potential such that its energy is given completely by its kinetic energy. In such situations, and only in such situations will the operator $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ be a 'kinetic energy operator', although even in such situations I don't think it is useful to view it in this way. I think a more useful way to interpret it is as the energy operator for a system where the energy is given by the kinetic energy, and by consequence it is therefore a 'kinetic energy operator'.
This distinction might seem a little pedantic but the reason it's important can be seen from the fail cases. One such fail case is the example you've given. But for a more obvious example, consider the harmonic oscillator, which if you haven't met already I'm sure you will some point soon. It's the same as what you've described except $V(x)$ has some quadratic dependence on x rather than a step at x=0. The ground state wavefunction of the Harmonic Oscillator is just a gaussian:
$\psi(x) = A exp(- \alpha x^2)$,
where $A$ and $\alpha$ are just constants, their precise values aren't important here. Importantly, if I applied $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ on this function, I would get:
$- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2} \psi(x) = - \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} (-2 \alpha + 4 \alpha^2 x^2) \psi(x)$,
which would suggest that the 'kinetic energy' of this state is $\frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} (2 \alpha - 4 \alpha^2 x^2)$ and thus somehow depends on position, rather than being a constant which we would prefer. This is not true and it is actually not possible to extract the kinetic energy of this state at all because it isn't really defined in this case.
An example of a situation where your method would work would be in the negative x part of your potential. Then if you applied $- \frac{ħ^{2}}{2m} \frac {d^{2}}{dx^2}$ onto your wavefunction, you would just get the first Schrodinger equation I wrote above and your eigenvalue would just be the energy E, as expected.
